# Cakephp 3 i18nFormat string for the number of weeks in a specified date

Tags: date-formatting, cakephp-3.x, week-number

How to get number of week for specific date in `cakephp 3`?

`$this->mydate->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')` will display year-month-date.

But what about string format for week number?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a closer look at the docs for `Cake\I18n\Time::i18nFormat()`, it tells you what you can pass as the format, and where to find a list of the accepted formatting patterns:

> [...] You can either pass [**IntlDateFormatter constants**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php#intl.intldateformatter-constants) as the first
> argument of this function, or pass a full ICU date formatting string
> as specified in the following resource:
> **https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax**.

**[Cookbook > Date & Time > Formatting > Cake\I18n\Time::i18nFormat()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#Cake%5CI18n%5CTime::i18nFormat)**

So long story short, the pattern letter for the week of the year is `w`, or `ww` if you want a leading zero, and for the week of the month it's `W` or `WW`.

Comment: Thanks :) your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @ndm the icu-project.org link is dead (kinda), I found [unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details), but unsure if it can be a replacement

Comment: @aexl They moved their docs. I've updated my answer with the new URL (the one you have there works too, it's simply the new API reference). I'll push a PR to update the CakePHP docs accordingly.